# Add XML element and save the file?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm pretty new to XML parsing with Python with minidom.

I have got this XML:

```xml
<filelist>
    <file id="1.jpg"></file>
</filelist>
```

I would like to add and then save to the same file the following row for example:

```xml
    <file id="2.jpg"></file>
```

I am doing the parsing using:

```
doc = minidom.parse('filelist.xml')
files = doc.getElementsByTagName('file')
for file in files:
      idFile = file.getAttribute("id")
      print(idFile)
```

How I can add that "element" and then save to same file?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your original code, the following additions were added to your code to accomplish adding an element and saving it back to the original file:

1. Create a new '`file`' element
2. Set the new '`file`' element '`id`' attribute
3. Retrieve the document root ('`filelist`') node
4. Append the new '`file`' element to the '`filelist`' node
5. Write updated XML back to original file

See updated code following with comments to match this list of additions.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse('filelist.xml')
# 1. Create a new 'file' element
new_file_element = doc.createElement('file')
# 2. Set the new 'file' element 'id' attribute
new_file_element.setAttribute('id', '2.jpg')
# 3. Retrieve the document root ('filelist') node
filelist_element = doc.documentElement
# 4. Append the new 'file' element to the 'filelist' node
filelist_element.appendChild(new_file_element)
files = doc.getElementsByTagName('file')
for file in files:
    idFile = file.getAttribute('id')
    print(idFile)
# 5. Write updated XML back to original file
with open('filelist.xml', 'w') as xml_file:
    doc.writexml(xml_file, encoding='utf-8')
```